# Does attacking a mimic stick your weapon to it?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

Gearing up to have my players beset by a mimic. I noticed their Adhesive trait says that *anything* that touches them sticks to them, as quoted below:

> **Adhesive (Object Form Only):** The mimic adheres to anything that touches it. A Huge or smaller creature adhered to the mimic is also Grappled by it (escape DC 13). Ability Checks made to escape this grapple have disadvantage.

My question revolves around a fighter making a melee attack against the mimic. Would the weapons stick to the mimic? and if so, would you have to make a strength (athletics) or dexterity (acrobatics) check to free your weapon after successfully hitting it each time?

The rest of the block is pretty clear that if you grab it or if it attacks/touches you that you are grappled. So I am assuming it would play the same for weapons, but I also feel making an escape roll after every swing of a weapon will get tedious during game play.

What is the RAW for this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### RAW, weapons stick to the mimic

The ability you quote does say that mimics stick to "*anything*" that touches them. Moreover, the description of the mimic specifically states (emphasis added, MM220),

> When it changes shape, a mimic excretes an adhesive that helps it seize prey and **weapons that touch it**. The adhesive is absorbed when the mimic assumes
>   its amorphous form and on parts the mimic uses to move itself.

Therefore, RAW, any weapon that hits the mimic will stick to it. That will make fighting it with a melee weapon pretty annoying, but PCs generally have access to attacks that aren't affected by this ability, such as spells and ranged attacks. Also, it's only sticky as long as it's mimicking something, and loses its stickiness in its amorphous form.

Comment: I am now picturing a mimic that looks like the GoT chair, except it's not actually mimicking it, it's just covered in weapons from previous attackers.

Comment: thanks a bunch! I read the lore about it but that line must have slipped through the cracks. Looks like my players are gonna have to think outside the box on this one XD

Comment: I feel that it is worth noting that this only applies while the mimic is in object form and if the mimic returns to its true form (for example to use its more damaging bite attack) the weapons will become unstuck

Comment: @J4m0nT045t does returning to the true form removes the already secreted adhesive?

Comment: Yes. Not only does the ability to adhere to objects only exist in the object form, the description reads 'The adhesive is absorbed when the mimic assumes its amorphous form and on parts the mimic uses to move itself.' (MM 220)